# Unable to create a front end form with ACF, WordPress, No ACF Frontend Display Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am attempting to create a form on the home page of an intranet that I am building using WordPress. I am attempting to create the form using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF). I have followed the instructions provided in the ACF documentation here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/.

I have read several answers where people have used a plugin called the ACF front-end display plugin with this URL:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display. This plugin appears to no longer exist. Do I need to spring for ACF Pro?

I am attempting to do this in my `front-page.php`. I added this line above `get_header();`.

```
acf_form_head();
```

I added this where I want the form to be:

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    )
));
```

This is the error that I get when I try to view the form, note that the submit button appears:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the free version of Advanced Custom Fields which (at the time of writing this) is `4.4.2`. All of the online documentation for ACF defaults to the version 5 documentation. ACF Pro is version `5.2.9`.

Creating new posts is not supported in version 4. The pro version must be used to use this function to create new posts.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/

Answer (score 0):

Well from the examples, at minimum you need it to be this (you are missing title and content):

```
    acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_title'    => true,
        'post_content'  => true,
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        )
    ));
```

But that also should be contained in the loop (i.e. `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`).

Comment: Can you provide a little more of the code in context?

Comment: Also v5 is structured differently than v4. You need custom functions with v4.